# Is there any reason why Linux distros can reconize USB devices instantly, but Windows takes 1+ minutes to?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, drivers

I have many USB drives and adapters. I often need to use them in a variety of places (library, home, someone's laptop, so on). It always seems to take Windows (7, 8, 10) over 1 minute to recognize any USB drive which I have not plugged in before. On a Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat, Slackware) computer, it recognizes the device instantly. By recognize, I mean detecting the device and installing the driver.

Devices (the most recent ones I remember):

- TP-Link WN725N mini wifi adaptor
- Kingston DTSE9H USB flash drive
- Kingston DT 101 G2 USB flash drive
- Lexar JumpDrive TwistTurn flash drive
- Linksys Wireless N USB Adapter (AE1200-CA)
- Samsung Bar 32GB 130MB/s USB 3.0 Flash Drive
- Logitech Touch Plus Wireless Keyboard (K400)
- Logitech Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo - Black (MK270)

and more which I do not remember.

Is there any reason for this, and if so then how can I speed up device recognition on Windows?

Comment: Just an untested theory on my end, but I think it has something to do with the fact that Windows device drivers are signed it and it may be verifying signatures as it loads and searches for drivers.  Newer versions of Windows are also checking WIndows Update by default.  Regarding verification of signatures, I think it is possible to disable that verification somehow.  If I find out I'll report back.

Comment: @LawrenceC Thank you! I'll look into this soon too.

Comment: I think I have found it. I'll just try it sometime this week

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the current answer don’t appropriately capture the difference. Windows also has most drivers available (like USB Mass Storage or HID). They reside in separate files, of course. This is very similar to most generic Linux kernel builds that have their drivers in separate modules.

However, Windows will create a separate device instance for each device, which is identified by the location it’s connected (very important) and the device itself. This process is what takes all that time. After the device instance has been registered, adding and removing is as fast as with Linux.

tl;dr: The initial process to associate a device with a driver is slow on Windows. There is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Linux too follow a similar procedure. When a new device is connected Linux assigns a mount point to it.

Comment: Can I somehow make it think every usb device is the same?

Comment: Also, a kind of unrelated question: Is there a reason why Windows thinks a Lexar USB needs 4 drivers, but a Kingston only needs 1?

Comment: @KolappanNathan And what would a mouse’s mount point be? ;) Linux (which is just the kernel) does no such thing. Neither does udev in its default configuration.

Comment: @geek1011 No, you can’t make them “the same” or even equal. How would that work? // Some drives don’t adhere to established standards (USB Mass Storage) and require custom drivers. They’re generally garbage. That being said, how did you even determine it “needs 4 drivers”?

Comment: @DanielB Because it on the installing device drivers, it says: USB Storage Device, USB Mass Storage Device, Lexar USB Device, Lexar USB Flash Drive

Comment: @DanielB It shows up in Windows Explorer after the first 2 drivers

Comment: @geek1011 The drivers you see installing depends on the manufacturer.

Comment: @DanielB _what would a mouse’s mount point be?_ You are correct. Linux assigns mount points only to storage devices it seems. I didn't think of it earlier. Your answer deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is because Linux does not scan your pen drive or any other device for drivers.Linux kernel contains all drivers by default and only checks for model and make(manufacturer) of the device. Also many drivers are added as Kernel modules by Distro providers. They almost cover our day to day use devices.

> The Linux Kernel source code contains many drivers (in the form of source code) in the drivers folder. - Linux.org

But windows will scan any newly inserted device for driver software. If a driver software is found it will install the driver software. You may seen a Installing driver prompt such as the one below.

[image: Driver install]

> how can I speed up device recognition on Windows?

You cannot. Windows cannot work with the device without installing the drivers. It is mandatory that Windows will scan a device for drivers when a device is connected for **first time** even when there is driver installed manually. This is because Windows will scan the device for an updated version of driver.

**References** :

1. [Linux kernal drivers - Linux.org](http://www.linux.org/threads/the-linux-kernel-drivers.4205/)

Comment: But this does not answer the second part of my question : How can I prevent this on Windows?

Comment: @geek1011 You cannot. Windows cannot work with the device without installing the drivers. For the first time a device is inserted Windows will take it's time.

Comment: But is there a way to skip some steps of this process (other than looking in Windows Update)?

Comment: @geek1011 Not that I know of.

Comment: Isn't it a security issue that Windows installs any drivers from any plugged-in devices without asking?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know about the security implemented. You should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer fully explained the *why*, but didn't address what to do about it. The simple answer is that any time you get a new USB  device, connect it to the machine when you're not in a hurry, so that Windows can do all of its checks and install the drivers it needs.  Then when you're in a hurry, the drivers will be there already, so you won't have to wait -- unless Windows decides to be annoying and tries to check for updates to the device's drivers.

Comment: He said he will be using devices variety of "places (library, home, someone's laptop, so on". It will not be possible to install drivers at an earlier time in all the places. However your point is a good one and will save time when in a hurry.

Comment: I read that as meaning a variety of his own computers. I would expect that a library computer to be configured to block driver installations, making most devices (other than data chips) useless, not just slow to connect. But I overlooked "someone's laptop"; if someone trusts him enough to share the computer, they're presumably going to trust his USB devices too -- but there's not much chance to set up in advance there.